# QTreeWidget: Find items on screen

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm facing a performance problem with my QTreeWidget.
Their values are updated periodically (every 100ms). To treat the value and display it demands a non-negligible time. So the more data, the slower the software runs.

Of course there are many areas that I can improve, but I think that the clearer is to not process data when not needed.

So the question is: ***how do I know which Items are in the area that is being shown in the screen?***

I've tried to check for visibility (each item and *visibilityRegion*, that returns me the whole tree. Don't want that.
I've tried to get the rectangle from the widget (*frameReqt*), same result as before.

Of course that if I don't update the whole model, once the user scroll, the other values, that were once hidden, will be out of data. But this is another concern.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to display a big amount of data in a tree view, you should probably use the [Qt Model/View system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html): a [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html) associated with [a subclass of QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html). This is a much better option for your use case, and as far as I know, it already implements a smart update system (that asks the model for items only in a displayable range).

For example, think about reimplementing [fetchMore()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#fetchMore) or [canFetchMore()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#canFetchMore) methods from the model class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Read a lot about it these fews days, and I did something nice like this. But my major problem was that he was trying to resize the rows to fit the new content _every time_ that I updated a value (I saw that on VS's Profiling thingy). I did: ui.treeWidget->setUniformRowHeights(true); and everything was fine :)

Comment: It helped, but since it didn't answered the main question, it wouldn't be right to accept the answed IMHO. I stil don't know how go the the items that are displayed on the window, that would help me even further.